# Google test: died but not with expected error

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I write a simple Death test case by c++. But i found that it always failed. The program expect some error information, but there is not anything.

toolchain: clang & clang++ 8.0.1
OS:Ubuntu 4.4.0-142-generic

```
#include <limits.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(DeathTest, Fool) {

      EXPECT_DEATH([]() -> void {
        volatile int* nasty_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x0);
        *(nasty_ptr) = 0;
      }(),
      "backtrace.*Segmentation fault");
}
```

Obviously, there should be some error information just like that:
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)". But the test result is failed:

```
Running main() from /home/jingzhao/coding/googletest/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from DeathTest
[ RUN      ] DeathTest.Fool
/home/jingzhao/coding/googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc:10: Failure
Death test: []() -> void { volatile int* nasty_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x0); *(nasty_ptr) = 0; }()
    Result: died but not with expected error.
  Expected: contains regular expression "backtrace.*Segmentation fault"
Actual msg:
[  DEATH   ]
[  FAILED  ] DeathTest.Fool (132 ms)
[----------] 1 test from DeathTest (132 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (132 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] DeathTest.Fool

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Comment: Death test on segmentation fault? This is wrong. Code should never end with segmentation fault, so this shouldn't be tested as expectation! Death test should verify that some **assertion** is fired in certain conditions. Note your test is based on undefined behavior so compiler can do lots of strange things.

Comment: @MarekR, I think catching a segmentation fault in this kind of test is OK. See doc for gtest: `We use the word "crash" here to mean that the process terminates with a non-zero exit status code. There are two possibilities: either the process has called exit() or _exit() with a non-zero value, or it **may be killed by a signal**.`

Comment: The segfault is a signal 11, so it must be OK on Linux and it is not available on Windows. The problem is that Jing expects a message, but the real message is empty: `Actual msg:`

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov: Quoting [GTest docs first sentences](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#death-tests): "In many applications, there are assertions that can cause application failure if a condition is not met. These sanity checks, which ensure that the program is in a known good state, are there to fail at the earliest possible time after some program state is corrupted."

Comment: Right, these assertions result in signal 6 as far as I understand. However segfaults must be also OK. The doc states `it may be killed by a signal`

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov I agree with your opinion. From log information:"died but not with expected error", there is no error information, although it died.

Comment: Code which ends with SEGFAULT is simply incorrect in any circumstances. You should not verify if your code is incorrect. You death test is used to verify that if library API is used incorrectly application will be killed with useful information. If you are considering segmentation fault as valid code behavior then there is nothing to discuss. Anyway in case segmentation fault system defines if and what kind of text will be provided not your production code, this means this test can't be portable.